# How to scrollIntoView only on initial render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am struggling to scroll the node into view only on initial render.
Here is what I am trying to do.

```
const [lastItemRef, setLastItemRef] = useState(null);
const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false);



useEffect(() => {
    if (lastItemRef !== null && !isScrolled) {
      lastItemRef.scrollIntoView({
        block: 'end',
        inline: 'center',
      });

      setIsScrolled(true);
    }
  }, [lastItemRef, isScrolled]);


[![return (
   <SomeList>
     <DeepItem ref={lastItemRef} /> 
   </SomeList>
)][1]][1]
```

[image]

[image]

** Check the screens **
`DeepItem` is is mentioned in the screen and I need to scroll into its view only once on the initial render.The strange thing is that when I remove `setIsScrolled(true);` the `scrollIntoView` is working but also is working on subseqent renders when I am trying to scroll the list up and down or left and right.
As I can somehow imagine DOM interaction is not happenning because it's waiting for the react to update the internal state and once it happens, `isScrolled` is already `false`.
In the second screen you can see the result without removing `setIsScrolled(true)`.

F.Y.I. - I am using MUI Table with `react-window FixedSizeList`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to have state `isScrolled` to handle that case. Instead of that, you can call `useEffect` with `[]` (no dependencies) that will trigger your logic only once after the first rendering.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (lastItemRef !== null) {
      lastItemRef.scrollIntoView({
        block: 'end',
        inline: 'center',
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

If `lastItemRef` is null initially, you can add it to the dependency list. It's always referred to the same object, so `useEffect` also triggers once after `lastItemRef` has a value.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (lastItemRef !== null) {
      lastItemRef.scrollIntoView({
        block: 'end',
        inline: 'center',
      });
    }
  }, [lastItemRef]);
```

Comment: I know about it, thanks, but in that case, lastItemRef is null.

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan I think we can add `lastItemRef` to the dependency list, I may help your case too because the ref is only populated once and never change under the same rendered component.